# Find the number of ways in which series can be won by either of them.

Tags: combinatorics

A and B play a unique game series in a chess tournament.They decide to play on till one of them wins 5 matches.If each match end only in win or loss.Find the number of ways in which series can be won by either of them.

---

Let W be win and L be loss.
Either of the team wins in one of the cases.
WWWW|W....1 way
WWWWL|W....$\frac{6!}{5!}$
WWWWLL|W.......$\frac{7!}{2!5!}$
WWWWLLL|W....$\frac{8!}{3!5!}$
WWWWLLLL|W......$\frac{9!}{4!5!}$
WWWWLLLLL.....$\frac{9!}{4!5!}$
These add up to $336$ but the answer given is $252$.I dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: maybe you made a counting error there are 5 ways for the second one.  etc.

Answer (score 3):

This may also be described as "best out of nine". If we simply assume that all games after the winner is found are lost by the loser, there are precisely $9\choose 5$ way of the winner to win exactly 5 out of 9 rounds.